# Consecutive if-conditions in PHP

Tags: php

If you have two consecutive conditions in PHP, do they both get evaluated, or is the if-case evaluation cancelled if the first condition already failed (so the result of the second condition wouldn't matter)?

```
if (condition1 && condition2) { }
```

Comment: like this both conditions need to be true. if you use || it will be either of the conditions need to be true. so if first condition is false it indeed skips

Comment: In the case of `&&`, if the first condition fails, it skips the entire `if` section. If the first is true, it will move to the second. If second is true, it will enter the condition, else skip it

Comment: @Nic Possibly a duplicate, but the term "Short-Circuit Evaluation" was unknown to me before. Thanks to the answers here, not anymore.

Comment: Hi @Garrin, no worries - I don't blame you for not knowing that term, or not finding that other question. However, because your question is practically the same as that other question, I've flagged this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of the first condition makes evaluating the second condition unnecessary, PHP won't evaluate it (the second condition). This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), a term that is also meantioned in [PHP's documentation on logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Here is a small example to prove it:

```
<?php

function foo() {
    echo 'Bar';
    return true;
}

if (false && foo()) { }
```

Because PHP uses Short-circuit evaluation, `foo()` will not be executed, and therefore `Bar` will not be printed on the screen.

Because 'Test' will never be `echo`ed, you can conclude that if the first condition returns `false`, the second condition is never evaluated.

The same works for `||` (OR) operators, but the other way around:

```
<?php

function foo() {
    echo 'Bar';
    return true;
}

if (true || foo()) { }
```

Since the first condition is already `true`, there is no need to evaluate the second one. Again, `foo()` is not executed, so you'll get an empty screen.

Answer (score 11):

PHP uses [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so the second condition would not even be evaluated if the first one is false.

Comment: Nice reference table :}

Comment: +1 for using the correct terminology

Comment: @neelsg the part about the bitwise operator is NOT true. Both will be evaluated, but might yield an incorrect result! `var_dump(true & 10);` outputs: `int(0)`

Comment: @nl-x, it would mostly work, but you are correct that there may be some unwanted side effects. If have removed it, since there are more correct ways of getting around the issue anyway

Comment: Learn something new everyday, love the information!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `&&`, if the left condition fail the right ones wont be evaluated

```
if (statement1 && statement2)
{
    //If the left part is false, the right part is not even checked
}


if (statement1 || statement2)
{
    //if the left part is false, the right part is checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an AND. And PHP is lazy as hell. If the first functions returns false, it will not touch the other functions. Its the same with OR. If you use it, PHP is lazy and only evaluates as long as necessary.

```
if(condition1() || condition2())
```

If `condition1()` returns `true`, condition2 will be untouched. Its nice to know for performance, always evaluate the fast functions first in that case.^^